# C++ - Namespaces with Classes

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

I just need a refresher on this topic but I can't really find the answers online.

If you have a class called `Dog`

```
class Dog
{
public:
    void Dog::woof()
    {
        return; 
    }   
};
```

- Must every single function inside of `Dog` start with `Dog::`? That's how I've always done it but I want to ask is there **any** situation where that is not the case? If I don't put `Dog::` does that mean it can be used like a static method from Java? Ex. `Dog.woof();` instead of `myDogObj.woof();`
- Does the fact that we are using the `::` operator mean that `Woof` is in the namespace of `Dog`, even though `Dog` is not a namespace? If that's true, does that mean classes automatically create themselves as a namespace as well?
- Why do we put `Dog::` to tell C++ that it's a method that belongs to `Dog` while the very fact that it's inside of `class Dog` essentially states that already? Isn't that redundant?
- Is there any case where `Dog::woof` could be declared somehow inside of a namespace or nested namespace? Ex. `Park::Trail::Dog::woof() { return; }`

Would you have to do:

```
class Dog
{
public:
    namespace Park
    {
        namespace Trail
        {
            void Dog::woof()
            {
                return; 
            }       
        }   
    }   
};
```

Comment: The last example is nonsense, you can't have a namespace *inside* of a class.

Comment: What if I were to declare `woof` in the class, then define it outside of the class but I put that function definition inside of a namespace? Ex. `namespace Park { void Dog::woof()  { return; } }`

Comment: Unless the declaration of `Dog` is inside the `Park` namespace, it won't work. Jus try it, you'll see.

Answer (score 2):

> Must every single function inside of Dog start with Dog::? That's how
>   I've always done it but I want to ask is there any situation where
>   that is not the case? If I don't put Dog:: does that mean it can be
>   used like a static method from Java? Ex. Dog.woof(); instead of
>   myDogObj.woof();

No method has to start with `Dog::` inside the class definition, only outside of it.

> Does the fact that we are using the :: operator mean that Woof is in
>   the namespace of Dog, even though Dog is not a namespace? If that's
>   true, does that mean classes automatically create themselves as a
>   namespace as well?

Yes, in the scope of `Dog`.

> Why do we put Dog:: to tell C++ that it's a method that belongs to Dog
>   while the very fact that it's inside of class Dog essentially states
>   that already? Isn't that redundant?

Yes, which is why you don't do it.

Comment: You can define a method inside of `Dog` even if you place it outside of the bracket confines of `class Dog`? Does that method that you define outside of `Dog` have to be in the same `cpp` file as `Dog`?

Comment: @Hatefiend You declare it inside Dog and you can define it anywhere else. No it doesn't.

Comment: Is there a way to declare and define outside or can you only define outside? (I'm guessing the later)

Comment: You can do both. Either in the class declaration (in your header file normally) or in a seperate .CPP file (class definition)